# Select values from Button classified as listbox using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape the data from this website:

https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/england/premier-league/17

I'd like to get the data for several seasons, so I need to change it using this button.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk23Z.png)

The problem is that the this list is actually specified as button:

```
<button type="button" id="downshift-2-toggle-button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="downshift-2-label downshift-2-toggle-button" class="sc-fEXmlR bwfzPL"><div display="flex" class="sc-hLBbgP sc-eDvSVe gjJmZQ fRddxb"><span color="onSurface.nLv1" class="sc-bqWxrE ieHJKE">22/23</span><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#222226" class="sc-jSUZER btAxHh" style=""><path fill="#222226" d="M7 10L12 15 17 10z"></path></svg></div></button>
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li//button[@id='downshift-2-toggle-button']")
sel = Select(dropdown)
sel.select_by_visible_text("21/22")
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the 'Select' type dropdown, it is a 'li' type dropdown, so you cannot use 'Select', instead try this code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/england/premier-league/17")

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-fnGiBr.kdHYZX #downshift-2-toggle-button").click()
time.sleep(1)
list_of_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div/ul[@id='downshift-2-menu']/li")

option_to_select = "93/94"

for i in range(len(list_of_options)):
    option = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div/ul[@id='downshift-2-menu']/li[" + str(i + 1) + "]").text
    time.sleep(0.2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div/ul[@id='downshift-2-menu']/li[" + str(i + 1) + "]").location_once_scrolled_into_view
    if option_to_select == option:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div/ul[@id='downshift-2-menu']/li[" + str(i + 1) + "]").click()
        break
```